# error when passing function pointer as a argument in python

Tags: python, ctypes

**Note:** dll written in C++ and accessing in python

```
import ctypes
import os
from ctypes import*

def plateDetectedCallback(hEngine, hPlate):
    print "successfully loaded"
    pass

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("some dll path")
hLPRRarams = lib.LPRParams_Create()
hEngine = lib.LPREngine_Create(hLPRRarams, True,plateDetectedCallback) # error in this line
```

1. plateDetectedCallback is a callback function or function pointer
2. Now I want to call callback function as per documentation like `plateDetectedCallback(LPRENGINE hEngine, LPRPLATE hPlate)`

I tried in different ways to call the callback function but failed. please, Can any one help in this. Thankyou

I am getting the exception like:

`NameError: name 'plateDetectedCallback' is not defined`

Comment: Where is plateDetectedCallback actually defined? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: @user8035311 in documentation they gave like **plateDetectedCallback(LPRENGINE hEngine, LPRPLATE hPlate)**. can you tell me how I can implement. `LPRENGINE` and `LPRPLATE` are pointer objects. I implemented same as shown Documentation but no use

Comment: Define this function in your code.

Comment: @user8035311 I edited my post

Comment: Your function should be right under "from ctypes import*"

Comment: Usually when you want to **use** something, you need to **have** it first. This also applies to code: if you want to use a var/func you need to have it defined at that point. Move the func definition before the line that throws the error. This is just 1st step. there are more to be done.

Comment: now I am getting exception like `File "anpr.py", line 5
    def plateDetectedCallback(LPRENGINE hEngine, LPRPLATE hPlate):
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It's the same thing (but with other symbols). You should check a *Python* tutorial first, to get you over these kinds of errors.

Comment: In python can I pass parameters something like this `plateDetectedCallback(LPRENGINE hEngine, LPRPLATE hPlate):` as done in c++

Comment: How does the `LPREngine_Create` signature (*C*) look like? In *Python* you don't specify argument types. Seriously, you should get yourself used to *Python* before diving into *ctypes* (as it's a bit unusual for *Python* programmers).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Issue Using @CFUNCTYPE decorator

```
    @c.CFUNCTYPE(None, c_void_p, c_void_p)
    def plateDetectedCallback(hEngine, hPlate):
        .....
        .....
```

None is the return type of dll(i.e void), c_void_p is a void pointer

make sure to import the ctypes